# Reading binary from file to dynamicly allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, bitmap, binary

Quick question:

Im playing around abit with Bitmaps and is trying to load the colour table, but I'm getting a

```
 Access violation writing location 0xcccccccc.
```

Before I send the array pointer in to the read function i dynamicly allocated a new array. I just wanted to confirm that I am doing it the rigth way.

Code:

```
numColours = 1 << bitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount;
if( bitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount == 1 ||
    bitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount == 4 ||
    bitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount == 8){
    rgbquad = new RGBQUAD[numColours];
    in.read((char*)rgbquad, sizeof(RGBQUAD)*numColours);
}
```

Comment: What does the RGBQUAD structure look like?

Comment: Are you sure that´t the problematic code part?

Comment: `0xcccccccc` is usually a value for uninitialized variable, which can't be seen from this example.

Comment: @skreborn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
deviantfan yh, however i solved it now, it was a stupid error of me.

Answer (score 0):

To anwser my own question, yes, this is a valid way of doing it!